# MSI 990FXA-GD80 -- Won't boot; no POST LED

Tags: boot, motherboard

I've got an MSI 990FXA-GD80 motherboard. As of yesterday, the power button will turn on the fans, but nothing else happens. Even the POST LED's on the bottom of the board don't light up. Any thoughts of how I can diagnose this further?

Comment: After a bit more research, I tried a Hail Mary and popped out the CMOS battery overnight, even though I'd already tried clearing the CMOS by the jumper and the button provided on this motherboard. It did the trick!